# SSRS: Passing parmeters to drillthrough action for connected report

Tags: reporting-services

I have an action calling another report. How do I pass parameters to the report being connected to?
When setting up the action, I can define a parameter, but where in the called report do I indicate that the parameter is populated from the report calling it?

thanks  guys
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Create the parameter in the report being called first. Then , when you go to action -> go to report -> add, the parameter should appear in the 'name' drop down box.
You should not have to do anything further to the report being called, it will now 'know' to collect the value being passed.